# File permission issue while creating angular project

Tags: angular, file

I tried to create an **angular project** but got this error
`EPERM: operation not permitted,` mkdir `'D:\newassign\store'`
Checked all the **permission** still can't get whats **wrong**

**EPERM: operation not permitted,** mkdir `'D:\newassign\store'`

Comment: please share more details, which os are you using, are you running as administrator?